# failure of cvtColor function in opencv

Tags: opencv

i am just learning image processing but cvtColor function is not working properly. it is showing following error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "harriscorner.py", line 6, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

actually i am trying harris corner detection method but cvtColor fucion is not working. help from anyone will be appreciated.
here is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'chessboard.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How many channels are there in `chessboard.jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is showing error at the very first cvtColor after reading from a file, it is possible that the imread operation was not successful.

Start by ensuring that your image is correctly read:

```
filename = 'chessboard.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imshow("src",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)#proceed to remaining code when you press a key
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

If you're not able to see you image in this imshow, then check if the filePath is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filename = './chessboard.jpg'
```